# I need to implement collapsible filter in Spotfire using Jquery

Tags: jquery, spotfire

I need the code to do the collapsible filter in Spotfire using Jquery. I am not much aware of jquery but i guess its the same as implementing Javascript in text area.

Comment: you should do some research first before simply asking for the code. There are solutions available to your problem online. Anyways I have provided the solution below. Make sure you put some effort on implementation and then let me know in case you are stuck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use jquery accordian.

```
<DIV id="accordian">
  <H3>Filter1</H3>
  <DIV>
    <p style="DISPLAY: block">
      <SpotfireControl id="f4b03c6669c94865b3faa23d9f360160" />
    </p>
  </DIV>

  <H3>Filter2</H3>
  <DIV>
    <p style="DISPLAY: block">
      <SpotfireControl id="78690b9955944fe2804b1ba2de1fb9c2" />
    </p>
  </DIV>

  <H3>Filter3</H3>
  <DIV>
    <p style="DISPLAY: block">
      <SpotfireControl id="54dc77ac79c548fe96216e218d7dd07f" />
    </p>
  </DIV>

  <H3>Filter4</H3>
  <DIV>
    <p style="DISPLAY: block">
      <SpotfireControl id="ffa344dc2fa64b1696afbae0e99c88b1" />
    </p>
  </DIV>
</DIV>
```

Note: use your spotfire control (filter) ids
2) Use below javascript

```
//Declaring Variables

//Accordian variables
var headBkgColor = "#848484";
var leftContentMargin = "-20px";


//Applying accordian
$("#accordian").accordion({ 

heightStyle: "content" ,
collapsible: true

});

//Applying CSS

//Header background color
$(".ui-accordion .ui-accordion-header").css({
  "background": headBkgColor
});
//Left content margin
$("#accordian p").css({
  "margin-left":leftContentMargin
});
```

Comment: how to link a particular column into the Filter in your code. Can you elaborate a bit on your code with steps so that i can implement in Spotifre. I am confused whether both codes go into a single variable and if they goto 2 variables how should i link them?

Comment: i am not sure which variables are you talking about. Let me explain a bit more. The second script applies accordian functionality to the HTML. You have to add a javascript and inside that put the second script.

The first script is the HTML code which you have to put in edit HTML window. You have to add Filters manually and the replace the existing spotfire control tags("<SpotfireControl id="f4b03c6669c94865b3faa23d9f360160" />")  with the ones that you created.